# Jquery UI 1.12.1 : Issues dynamically adding checkboxradio widget when within a tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an issue when adding dynamic checkradioboxes within tabs.  If I add the checkbox outside of a Tab, it generates correctly.  If I add within a Tab, the 'Tick' becomes a ^ icon.

```
<input type="submit" value="Add" class="submit1" name="btnGo" id="btnGo" />

<div id="z" style="margin: 0px auto; width:800px; height:30px;"></div>

<div id="tabDiv" class="tabsDiv880_W1400">
    <ul>
        <li class="tabWidth110" ><a class="tabWidthHref90" href="#tabs-Detail"     >Detail</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-Detail"       class="tabsPanelH850" >
        <div id="y" style="margin: 0px auto; width:800px; height:30px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code

```
    $('#btnGo').unbind('click').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#z')
            .html('<label for="wsKh"></label><input Type="checkbox" name="wsKh" id="wsKh" checked="checked "/>' +
                        '<label for="wsKh1"></label><input Type="checkbox" name="wsKh1" id="wsKh1" checked="checked " disabled="disabled" />');
        $('#wsKh,#wsKh1').checkboxradio();

        $('#y')
            .html('<label for="wsyKh"></label><input Type="checkbox" name="wsyKh" id="wsyKh" checked="checked "/>' +
                        '<label for="wsyKh1"></label><input Type="checkbox" name="wsyKh1" id="wsyKh1" checked="checked " disabled="disabled" />');
        $('#wsyKh,#wsyKh1').checkboxradio();
    });
```

The problem is that the background-postion-x is wrong and I don't know what do do to correct it (the icon being shown is the ^ and not the tick).  I've made no changes.

Correct styling :

```
background-position-x:
-64px   jquery-ui.theme.min.css:5.ui-icon-check
initial jquery-ui.theme.min.css:5.ui-state-checked
initial jquery-ui.theme.min.css:5.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus, .ui-button:hover, .ui-button:focus
-64px   jquery-ui.min.css:7.ui-icon-check
initial jquery-ui.min.css:7.ui-state-checked
initial jquery-ui.min.css:7.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus, .ui-button:hover, .ui-button:focus
```

Incorrect styling :

```
background-position-x:
initial jquery-ui.theme.min.css:5.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus, .ui-button:hover, .ui-button:focus
initial jquery-ui.min.css:7.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus, .ui-button:hover, .ui-button:focus
-64px   jquery-ui.theme.min.css:5.ui-icon-check
initial jquery-ui.theme.min.css:5.ui-state-checked
-64px   jquery-ui.min.css:7.ui-icon-check
initial jquery-ui.min.css:7.ui-state-checked
```

Comment: I created this in fiddle and it doesn't seem to be broken. Perhaps you have other css that is messing with your background-position?

Comment: I've added this fiddle which shows the problem:  https://jsfiddle.net/Keith_DH/u536gssv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery UI, they have a sprite sheet of all the icons then use background position to display them. (This saves them file space).

For a checkmark, they have this declared:

```
.ui-icon-check {
    background-position: -64px -144px;
    background-position-x: -64px;
    background-position-y: -144px;
}
```

However, when your checkbox is in the container `ui-widget-content`, they appply a background-position of `initial`, but when in a tab, it is set to `50% 50%`.

What you can do is either target all of your checkboxes like so:

```
.ui-icon-check {
    background-position: -64px -144px !important;
    background-position-x: -64px;
    background-position-y: -144px;
}
```

or, target only the checkboxes in `.ui-widget-content`.

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon-check {
    background-position: -64px -144px !important;
}
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u536gssv/7/), I chose to target all check boxes.

Comment: That's great thank you.  I noticed that there is another problem on my original and your amended fiddle, in that after the check box is unchecked, there is an erroneous character (icon) remaining which is not there if the check box is outside the tab.  
I've added :

.ui-icon-blank {
 background-position  :16px 16px !important;
 background-position-x :16px;
 background-position-y :16px;
}